# Email in salesforce

Tags: rest-api, email, tasks

I have been trying to figure out the `REST API` for email synchronization with Salesforce, and realized that there is no formal `Email` object in the `API sobjects`. 
Digging deeper, i found out that even though Salesforce hasn't provided a formal 'object', an Email is just a special task with-

1. `Subject: "Email: "`
2. Status: Completed
3. All mail details like CC, BCC, Subject, Body summarized in the `Description` field.
4. Sender is the `OwnerId`, Receiver is `WhoId`.

And of-course.. other such nuances.

**My question is-** Through the REST API, if i precisely imitate Salesforces' syntax and semantics and log emails as special tasks- will i be *essentially* logging emails? Is this all there is to Email logging in Salesforce or is there more to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct, its just a Task completed in a particular way. (except for Email2Case which has a special EmailMessage object, which IIRC, isn't in the public API). The Task approach is what the Outlook integration and others (e.g. Maildrop) do.